# strange way of working in DFS in one of leetcode questions

Tags: python, permutation, depth-first-search, mutable, letter

I think this is just about some fundamental difference about Python function and data structure but I wasn't able to figure out why the method II doesn't working it seems the variable res also change values during the traverse but just not as expected, can anyone tell me why.

Method 1:

```
class Solution:
    def numTilePossibilities(self, tiles: str) -> int:
        
        n=len(tiles)
        d={}
        for e in tiles:
            d[e]=d.get(e,0)+1
            
        s=''
        res=[0]   ## only difference
        self._help(d,s,res,n)
        return res[0]
        
    def _help(self,d,s,res,n):

        if len(s)<n:
            for e in d:
                if d[e]>0:
                    d[e]-=1
                    res[0]+=1
                    print(s)
                    print(res)
                    self._help(d,s+e,res,n)
                    d[e]+=1
```

Method 2:

```
class Solution:
    def numTilePossibilities(self, tiles: str) -> int:
        
        n=len(tiles)
        d={}
        for e in tiles:
            d[e]=d.get(e,0)+1
            
        s=''
        res=0
        self._help(d,s,res,n)
        return res 0
        
    def _help(self,d,s,res,n):

        if len(s)<n:
            for e in d:
                if d[e]>0:
                    d[e]-=1
                    res+=1
                    print(s)
                    print(res)
                    self._help(d,s+e,res,n)
                    d[e]+=1
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  "Doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Also, when asking for help, please de-minify your code. No whitespace and all-single-letter var names make it difficult to assist.

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is because you can't pass integers by reference in Python, but you can pass list objects in and mutate properties on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an array in the first one, the second one is an `int`.

This'd simply pass through:

```
class Solution:
    def numTilePossibilities(self, tiles):
        frequencies = collections.Counter(tiles)
        product = 1
        for f in frequencies.values():
            product *= -~f

        possibles = 0
        for num in range(1, product):
            digits = []
            for f in frequencies.values():
                digits.append(num % -~f)
                num //= -~f
            temp = math.factorial(sum(digits))
            for digit in digits:
                temp //= math.factorial(digit)
            possibles += temp

        return possibles
```

---

```
class Solution:
    def numTilePossibilities(self, tiles):
        frequencies = collections.Counter(tiles)
        product = 1
        for f in frequencies.values():
            product *= (f + 1)

        possibles = 0
        for num in range(1, product):
            digits = []
            for f in frequencies.values():
                digits.append(num % -~f)
                num //= (f + 1)
            temp = math.factorial(sum(digits))
            for digit in digits:
                temp //= math.factorial(digit)
            possibles += temp

        return possibles
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-tile-possibilities/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.